# Parsing <sup> tag inside <td>

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to xpath parse an HTML document containing the following line:

```
<td class="ficha ficha_izq">Emisiones de CO<sub>2</sub> (gr/km)</td>
```

I'm using scrapy, and the result is:

```
[<Selector xpath='//td[contains(@class,"ficha_izq")]/node()' data=u'Emisiones de CO'>, <Selector xpath='//td[contains(@class,"ficha_izq")]/node()' data=u'<sub>2</sub>'>, <Selector xpath='//td[contains(@class,"ficha_izq")]/node()' data=u' (gr/km)'>]
```

so, three items instead of just one. I don't mind about the  tag, so how would I get a single item containing:

```
Emisiones de CO2 (gr/km)
```

This is not a single case, I've several items containing the  tag, so I need some programatic solution.

Any clue?

thanks!!

NOTE: Using text() instead of node() does not help:

```
[<Selector xpath='//td[contains(@class,"ficha_izq")]/text()' data=u'Emisiones de CO'>, <Selector xpath='//td[contains(@class,"ficha_izq")]/text()' data=u' (gr/km)'>]
```

Comment: The question title says `sup` but the questipn itself says `sub`. And this does not look like a *parsing* problem.

Answer (score 1):

This xpath should work `//td[contains(text(),'Emisiones de CO')]/node()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `w3lib.html.remove_tags`. You can use it with an `ItemLoader`.

```
In [1]: html = '<td class="ficha ficha_izq">Emisiones de CO<sub>2</sub> (gr/km)</td>'

In [2]: sel = Selector(text=html)

In [3]: map(remove_tags, sel.xpath('//td').extract())
Out[3]: [u'Emisiones de CO2 (gr/km)']
```

Alternatives using XPath or CSS selectors:

```
In [4]: u''.join(sel.xpath('//td[contains(@class,"ficha_izq")]//text()').extract())
Out[4]: u'Emisiones de CO2 (gr/km)'

In [5]: u''.join(sel.css('td.ficha_izq ::text').extract())
Out[5]: u'Emisiones de CO2 (gr/km)'
```

Notice the space between `td.ficha_izq` and `::text`, and that `::text` CSS pseudo element is a Scrapy extension to CSS selectors.

Comment: in your case, you are losing the information as you dont really need the part inside the sub or sup to be identified, however lets say it was the question asking 2 <sup>3</sup> = 8? using your technique this would fetch 23 = 8 which is actually incorrect, how do you get say 2^3 = 8?